# Does retina screen increase the computing

Tags: ios, opengl-es

I have a question about the retina screen.

For example, I draw a rectangle on screen by OpenGL with shading , the size is the same as iPhone screen.

For iPhone without retina screen, the size is 320*480. From my understanding, there would be 320*480 times fragment shader computing. For iphone with retina, is the computing becomes 320*480*4? Or still 320*480.

Best Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends. If you just render into a 320x480 framebuffer, you just render into a 320x480 framebuffer and let the device do some simple upscaling. However, if you render into a 640x960 framebuffer, render into a 640x960 framebuffer. Rendering into a higher resolution always comes at its costs, you can see this on the PC quite good were your computer might be able to handle 1024x768 pixels at full settings but only medium settings on 1920x1200. Luckily, the latter doesn't apply to iOS since the Hardware scaled with the display, in fact, you are even able to render much higher quality scenes on an iPhone 4 with retina display support than you are able to do on an iPhone 3GS.

For "the new iPad"... who knows, but if the GPU is really two times faster than the one in the iPad 2, its gonna be able to really draw astonishing scenes in full resolution.

Comment: It also depends on if you are fill-rate limited or if your bottleneck is in processing large amounts of geometry. I had an application with massive geometry, yet simple shaders, and saw very little slowdown in stepping from iPhone 3G S to iPhone 4 Retina framebuffers. However, a later version of this application which had heavy fragment shaders was much slower on the larger screen size of the iPhone 4. The iPad 2 has some very solid fragment processing performance, but the Retina iPad would need to scale its fragment processing by 4X to maintain this with that many more pixels.

Comment: As a side note, you may need to explicitly set the scale factor of your UIView that hosts the OpenGL ES content using `self.contentScaleFactor = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];` in order to enable Retina-resolution rendering within that view.